# HttpPostedFileBase always get null in MVC Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, razor-pages, httppostedfilebase

I have created one form where user can upload profile photo, and it stores in database as byte array.
but in post method i'm getting the value of **HttpPostedFileBase** property is null.

```
<form id="profile-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                 <img id="output" style="height:200px; width:200px;" />
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <input asp-for="Input.ProfilePhoto" type="file" onchange="loadFile(event)" class="form-control">
            </div>
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Upload">Save</button>
   </div>
</form>

public class Input
{
      [Display(Name = "Profile Photo")]
      public HttpPostedFileBase ProfilePhoto { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{

}
```

Comment: Did you make sure to add enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form?

Comment: I have already added that `<form id="profile-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: then change HttpPostedFileBased -> IFormFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET Core equivalent to `HttpPosteFileBase` is `IFormFile`:

```
[BindProperty]
public IFormFile Upload { get; set; }

public async Task OnPostAsync()
{
    var file = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "uploads", Upload.FileName);
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await Upload.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
}
```

You also need to decorate the `IFormFile` property (or the class that it is in) with the `[BindProperty]` attribute.

Ref: [Uploading Files in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/file-upload)